# Laplacian of $x^2$

Tags: fourier-transform

It is possible to calculate the Laplacian of a function by its integral representation?    More precisely

Since $-\partial_{x}^2(x^2)=-2$ and $-\partial_{x}^2 u(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\xi^2 \widehat{u}(\xi))(x)$ ($u$ adecuate)
Then
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{ix\xi} \xi^2 \widehat{\xi^2} d\xi=-2?$$
Or the above is not true since $x^2$ is not a suitable function, for example, it is not Schwartz, and that does not allow a Fourier representation for the Laplacian operator.

Comment: The Fourier transform is defined of $x^2$ is defined as a distribution: $$\mathcal{F}\{x^2\}(\xi)=-2\pi\delta''(\xi).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u(x) = x^2$. The distributional Fourier transform of $u$ is
$$
\mathcal{F}\{u\} 
= \mathcal{F}\{x^2 \mathbf{1}\} 
= (i\partial)^2 \mathcal{F}\{\mathbf{1}\} 
= (i\partial)^2 (2\pi \delta)
= -2\pi \delta'',
$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is the constant function with value $1$ everywhere.

The distributional Fourier transform of the second derivative of $u$ is
$$
\mathcal{F}\{u''\}(\xi)
= (i\xi)^2 \mathcal{F}\{u\}(\xi)
= (i\xi)^2 (-2\pi \delta'')(\xi)
= 2\pi \xi^2\delta''(\xi)
= 2\pi \cdot 2\delta(\xi)
= \mathcal{F}\{2\mathbf{1}\}(\xi).
$$

We can of course turn this around to get more what you want:
$$
\partial^2 u
= \partial^2 \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{-2\pi\delta''\}
= \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{(ix)^2 \cdot (-2\pi\delta'')\}
= 2\pi \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{x^2 \delta''\} \\
= 2\pi \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{2\delta\}
= 2\pi \cdot \frac{1}{2\pi}\mathcal{F}\{2\delta\}(-x)
= 2\mathbf{1}.
$$

---

Showing $\xi^2\delta''(\xi)=2\delta(\xi)$ that is used above:
$$
\langle x^2\delta'', \varphi \rangle
= \langle \delta'', x^2\varphi \rangle
= \langle \delta, (x^2\varphi)'' \rangle
= \langle \delta, 2\varphi + 4x\varphi' + x^2\varphi'' \rangle
\\
= 2\varphi(0) + 4\cdot 0 \cdot\varphi'(0) + 0^2 \cdot \varphi''(0)
= 2\varphi(0)
= \langle 2\delta, \varphi \rangle.
$$